# Can I somehow remove animation in case of push segues

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Can I somehow remove animation in case of push segues? If yes, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a push you should have a UINavigationController. Just do:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
```

Comment: What is the difference between pushViewContoller and presentViewContoller methods?

Comment: pushViewController is used with a navigationController to create a navigationStack. So for example if I have a tableVC, in the `didselectrowatindexpath` I'll do a pushViewController to a detailVC to show the details of that cell. This allows me to automatically have a back button that will push me back to the previous screen. PresentViewController doesn't have the navigationStack - I believe it actually is a modal that just places the new VC on top.

Comment: But I can dismiss the modal view controller too similar to the "Back" button

Comment: True, but you'll have to create your own button and link it up with either a @selector or an IBAction on your modalVC. They're very similar, one is just used if you want a Navigation bar and one is if you don't need one. I just said `pushViewController` since usually Push segue implies a UINavigationController set up in the Storyboard. Either should work, just a matter of finding the one that fits your user flow :)